# How to view man hours in MS Project 2013

Tags: ms-project

I have created a sample project plan in MS Project 2013 with 3 resources. Some tasks are running in parallel while others are one after another. I am using standard calendar which is 8 hours a days, 40 hour a week.

How do I know man hours of my project plan? Is there some view available looking at which I can know the man hours of my project?

Answer (score 0):

Actually work shows your man/hours, man/days, etc. You can check this field on a project level, group task level, individual task level, resource assignment level and per resource (check Resource Usage view for that)